# Android Studio: Set and Transfer choosen Spinner Value to next Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner, drawable

I am programming a small game app in with every player gets to choose a drawable which is then set for the following activity which is the small game.

This is my code so far:

```
public class Nameeingabespieler2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME1";
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME2 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME2";
    public static final String Dinonametest1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler1";
    private TextInputLayout namespieler1;
    private TextInputLayout namespieler2;
    private ArrayList<DinoWahl> mDinoWahl;
    private DinoAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nameeingabespieler2);
        namespieler1 = findViewById(R.id.Spieler_1_input);
        namespieler2 = findViewById(R.id.Spieler_2_input);
        final TextView testtest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);        

        initList();

        final Spinner dinospinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner dinospinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        mAdapter = new DinoAdapter(this, mDinoWahl);
        dinospinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        dinospinner2.setAdapter(mAdapter);        


        dinospinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                DinoWahl clickedItem = (DinoWahl) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                String DinoName = clickedItem.getmDinoName();
                Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this,DinoName + " ausgewählt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        

            }              

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        dinospinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                DinoWahl clickedItem = (DinoWahl) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                String DinoName2 = clickedItem.getmDinoName();
                Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this,DinoName2 + " ausgewählt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              

            }


            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void initList(){
        mDinoWahl = new ArrayList<>();
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Brutus",R.drawable.alkdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Skitty",R.drawable.coolerdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Pharmi",R.drawable.drogendino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Luise",R.drawable.frauendino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Rex",R.drawable.koenigsdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Cookie",R.drawable.kochdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Divi",R.drawable.magierdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Fumu",R.drawable.shishadino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Dr. Saurum",R.drawable.streberdino));

            }

    private boolean wertspieler1() {
        String usernameInput = namespieler1.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if (usernameInput.isEmpty()) {
            namespieler1.setError("Spieler bitte eintragen");
            return false;
        } else if (usernameInput.length() > 15) {
            namespieler1.setError("Name zu lang");
            return false;
        } else {
            namespieler1.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean wertspieler2() {
        String usernameInput = namespieler2.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if (usernameInput.isEmpty()) {
            namespieler2.setError("Spieler bitte eintragen");
            return false;
        } else if (usernameInput.length() > 15) {
            namespieler2.setError("Name zu lang");
            return false;
        } else {
            namespieler2.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void starteaktivity(View view) {
        if (!wertspieler1() | !wertspieler2()) {
            return;
        }
        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spieler1id);
        String name1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Spieler2id);
        String name2 = editText2.getText().toString();


        if(name1.equals(name2)) {
            Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this, "bitte unterschiedliche Namen eingeben",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Trinkspiel2spieler.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME1, name1);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME2, name2);    

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my code so far and the most relevant Part is this one.

initList();

```
        final Spinner dinospinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner dinospinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        mAdapter = new DinoAdapter(this, mDinoWahl);
        dinospinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        dinospinner2.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        dinospinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                DinoWahl clickedItem = (DinoWahl) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                String DinoName = clickedItem.getmDinoName();
                Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this,DinoName + " ausgewählt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        

            }

       
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        dinospinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                DinoWahl clickedItem = (DinoWahl) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                String DinoName2 = clickedItem.getmDinoName();
                Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this,DinoName2 + " ausgewählt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }        

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

I don't get the choosen drawable to transfer and I really need your help.

EDIT
This is now my updated code
I have different classes

1. Nameeingabespieler2 (Class where I want the spinner type to be selceted and transfered to Trinkspiel2spieler.java)
2. Trinkspiel2spieler (this is the class where the Value should go and set the drawable for each player choosen in Nameeingabespieler2)
3. DinoWahl (for the Spinner)
4. DinoAdapter (adapter for the Spinner)

My Problem Now is, that I just wont get the Value transfered, even if I type(line: 162) everything as you said.
If I add (line 26 & 27) these Spinner declarations, they wont be used and if I remove (line: 41 & 42) then the app crashes.
But even with this version now, the next Activity (Trinkspiel2spieler) won't open.
I really don't know what to do now.
I am really sorry to bother you this much but I would be really really thankfull if you can help me.

```
public class Nameeingabespieler2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME1";
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME2 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME2";
    public static final String EXTRA_DINO1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler1";
    public static final String Dinonametest2 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler2";
    private TextInputLayout namespieler1;
    private TextInputLayout namespieler2;
    private Spinner dinospinner;
    private Spinner dinospinner2;
    private ArrayList<DinoWahl> mDinoWahl;
    private DinoAdapter mAdapter;




    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nameeingabespieler2);
        namespieler1 = findViewById(R.id.Spieler_1_input);
        namespieler2 = findViewById(R.id.Spieler_2_input);


        Spinner dinospinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner dinospinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);



        initList();



        mAdapter = new DinoAdapter(this, mDinoWahl);
        dinospinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        dinospinner2.setAdapter(mAdapter);



        dinospinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



                DinoWahl clickedItem = (DinoWahl) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                String DinoName = clickedItem.getmDinoName();
                Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this,DinoName + " ausgewählt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }



            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        dinospinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Context ctx = view.getContext();

                DinoWahl clickedItem = (DinoWahl) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                String DinoName2 = clickedItem.getmDinoName();
                Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this,DinoName2 + " ausgewählt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(ctx, Constants.class);
                intent.putExtra(Dinonametest2, DinoName2);




            }


            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void initList(){
        mDinoWahl = new ArrayList<>();
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Brutus",R.drawable.alkdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Skitty",R.drawable.coolerdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Pharmi",R.drawable.drogendino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Luise",R.drawable.frauendino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Rex",R.drawable.koenigsdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Cookie",R.drawable.kochdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Divi",R.drawable.magierdino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Fumu",R.drawable.shishadino));
        mDinoWahl.add(new DinoWahl("Dr. Saurum",R.drawable.streberdino));


    }

    private boolean wertspieler1() {
        String usernameInput = namespieler1.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if (usernameInput.isEmpty()) {
            namespieler1.setError("Spieler bitte eintragen");
            return false;
        } else if (usernameInput.length() > 15) {
            namespieler1.setError("Name zu lang");
            return false;
        } else {
            namespieler1.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean wertspieler2() {
        String usernameInput = namespieler2.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        if (usernameInput.isEmpty()) {
            namespieler2.setError("Spieler bitte eintragen");
            return false;
        } else if (usernameInput.length() > 15) {
            namespieler2.setError("Name zu lang");
            return false;
        } else {
            namespieler2.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void starteaktivity(View view) {
        if (!wertspieler1() | !wertspieler2()) {
            return;
        }
        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spieler1id);
        String name1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Spieler2id);
        String name2 = editText2.getText().toString();


        if(name1.equals(name2)) {
            Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this, "bitte unterschiedliche Namen eingeben",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Trinkspiel2spieler.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME1, name1);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME2, name2);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DINO1, ((DinoWahl) dinospinner.getSelectedItem()).getmDinoName());





            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }


}
```

Trinkspiel2spieler (not finished yet)

```
public class Trinkspiel2spieler extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trinkspiel2spieler);

    Button testnamentest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.namenbuttonid);

    testnamentest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startetest();
        }
    });

}

public void startetest() {

    //namen einlesen
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nametextstring1 = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_NAME1);
    String nametextstring2 = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_NAME2);
    String Dino_uerbertragung1 = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.Dinonametest1);
    String Dino_uerbertragung2 = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.Dinonametest2);


    String Namen[] = {nametextstring1,nametextstring2};

    //TextViews deklarieren
    TextView Textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameanzeige1);
    TextView Textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameanzeige2);
    ImageView Dinoimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    //TextView Textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameanzeige3);

    Random random = new Random();
    int num = random.nextInt(Namen.length);
    Textview1.setText(Namen[num]);

    if (Namen[num] == nametextstring1){
        if (Dino_uerbertragung1 == "Cookie")
        Dinoimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.kochdino);
    }
    else {
        Dinoimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.coolerdinomrk2klein);
    }



    Resources resources = getResources();
    String[] Trinkspielfragen = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Trinkspiel);

    Random random1 = new Random();
    int num2 = random1.nextInt(Trinkspielfragen.length);
    Textview2.setText(Trinkspielfragen[num2]);
    

}
```

}

DinoWahl

```
public class DinoWahl {
private String mDinoName;
private int mDinoWahl;

public DinoWahl(String Dinoname,int dinoBild) {
    mDinoName = Dinoname;
    mDinoWahl = dinoBild;
}

public String getmDinoName() {
    return mDinoName;

}

public int getDinoWahl(){
    return mDinoWahl;
}
```

}

DinoAdapter

```
public class DinoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <DinoWahl>{

public DinoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DinoWahl> DinoListe) {
    super(context, 0, DinoListe);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return initView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return initView(position, convertView, parent);
}

private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.dino_spinner, parent, false
        );
    }

    ImageView imageViewDino = convertView.findViewById(R.id.alkoholdino);
    TextView textViewName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.Dinoname);

    DinoWahl curentItem = getItem(position);

    if (curentItem != null) {
        imageViewDino.setImageResource(curentItem.getDinoWahl());
        textViewName.setText(curentItem.getmDinoName());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Constants

```
package com.example.die_trinkspielapp;
```

public class Constants {
public static final String EXTRA_NAME1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME1";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME2 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME2";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME3 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME3";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME4 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME4";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME5 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME5";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME6 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME6";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME7 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME7";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME8 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME8";
public static final String EXTRA_NAME9 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME9";

```
public static final String Dinonametest1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler1";
public static final String Dinonametest2 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler2";
public static final String Dinonametest3 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler3";
public static final String Dinonametest4 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler4";
public static final String Dinonametest5 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler5";
public static final String Dinonametest6 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler6";
public static final String Dinonametest7 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler7";
public static final String Dinonametest8 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler8";
public static final String Dinonametest9 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler9";
```

}

If you could help me here I will name one of the Drawables(Dinos) the player can choose after you if you want

Answer (score 1):

In your "starteaktivity" method you already have the answer, you just have to pass the selected value through extra to the intent.

**Edit:** To be more accurate

Hi @MarcStumpp

> I already tried that but the value wont go to the startactivity. It won't recognize it if I set it in the Spinner function as a String Value.Do you know how I could fix this?

I think your code is not complete in this case.

1. First you should declare your spinner as property variables of your Activity

```java
 public class Nameeingabespieler2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextInputLayout namespieler1;
    private TextInputLayout namespieler2;
    private Spinner dinospinner;
    private Spinner dinospinner2;
    private ArrayList<DinoWahl> mDinoWahl;
    private DinoAdapter mAdapter;
    ...
```

2. Then in your "starteaktivity" method you can get the value of the spinners to pass it as extra of your intent:

```java
    if(name1.equals(name2)) {
            Toast.makeText(Nameeingabespieler2.this, "bitte unterschiedliche Namen eingeben",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Trinkspiel2spieler.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME1, name1);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME2, name2);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME3, ((DinoWahl) dinospinner.getSelectedItem()).getmDinoName());
            ...
    
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

3. Retrieve the value in your "Trinkspiel2spieler" activity :

```java
public class Trinkspiel2spieler extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trinkspiel2spieler);

        String firstSpinnerVal = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_NAME3);
        ...


    }
}
```

**Advice**

I recommend you to create a Constants class for your extra like that for example:

```java
public class Constants {
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME1";
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME2 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME2";
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME3 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.EXTRA_NAME3";
    ...
    public static final String Dinonametest1 = "com.example.die_trinkspielapp.DinoSpieler1";
}
```

So like this you can use the same extra key across your activity and reduce risk of typo.

Comment: As Lu No says you can use Intent.putExtra(key, value) and pass the drawable as an integer to the "Trinkspiel2spieler" Activity.

Comment: I already tried that but the value wont go to the startactivity. It won't recognize it if I set it in the Spinner function as a String Value.Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Hi @MarcStumpp, I review my answer to be more accurate. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Hi @LuNo first I want to really thank you for everything and I adjusted my code. But I still have one Problem. The value, that is set for the choosen spinner value is trapped in the onItemselected function and I dont know how I can get it out of there. Did I do a stupid small mistake?

Comment: Hi @MarcStumpp you mean your "DinoName" and "DinoName2"? If you talk about these variables there are locals so it's normal. Maybe I miss something in your questions can you post a update of the code and details the new requierement you try to reach. As far as I know your initial issue should be fixed.

Comment: yes I mean the DinoName and DinoName2. So if they are local I can't get them in the Constants class? Is there a way to get them there then? If you want a update to the code I can upload it. And I wanted to thank you for everything so far :) you really helped me already much

Comment: You don't need these specific variables, since you can get catch the value at the moment of the launch of the next activity:
in "starteaktivity" func
`intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME3, ((DinoWahl) dinospinner.getSelectedItem()).getmDinoName());`
That retrieve the current value of the first spinner at the moment the function starteaktivity is called and set it as a extra for the intent. There is no "trapped" value about the spinner, the onItemSelected is just a listener.

The Constant are just use to store immutable variable like keys (eg: EXTRA_NAME1, EXTRA_NAME2...)

Comment: I don't know why but it still would't work. Now the Activity just crashes. I made a complete Update of the code if this helpes. You really safe me here. I really thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the line number on SO, the best is to copy and paste the lines that you think are an issue. Or take screenshot for example. Anyway, I copy the code in my IDE.

About the edited part:

> My Problem Now is, that I just wont get the Value transfered, even if I type(line: 162) everything as you said. If I add (line 26 & 27) these Spinner declarations, they wont be used and if I remove (line: 41 & 42) then the app crashes.

It's normal let's see what's android studio code inspector said:
[image: property variables]

1. You shouldn't keep you static key here as they are already in your Constant class now. If you keep double reference you will increase the risk of mistakes.
2. Pay attention to the color of your variable name, dinospinner and dinospinner2 are in grey why? The IDE can give you the answers(just over one of them) :
   [image: over wrong variable]
   Android Studio tells you that the value is never assigned ! To understand we should have a look at the line 41 and 42 you mentioned:
   [image: local variable]
   Here you are assigned the spinner value to a whole new variable, because of the Spinner at the beginning of the line. Once again, pay attention to the color of the variables dinospinner and dinospinner2. There are in white that mean there are local to the current function (OnCreate in this case). So you will not be able to call them outside of the onCreate.
   We can see at line 162 the dinospinner is purple:
   [image: 162 line]
   It's purple because you are refer to the property one but it's not assigned so when the code will be executed it will crash because of a NullPointerException because it was never assigned.
   To make it work you should remove Spinner at lines 41 and 42
   [image: 4142fixed]

> But even with this version now, the next Activity (Trinkspiel2spieler)
> won't open. I really don't know what to do now. I am really sorry to
> bother you this much but I would be really really thankfull if you can
> help me.

In the next activity, I don't see a update about your extras. If you want your first spinner value you should at least get it with the key "EXTRA_DINO1" if I update my anwser:

```
        String firstSpinnerVal = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_DINO1);
```

Please note that "EXTRA_DINO1" should be define in Constant and not in your activity.

On my side I was able to launch the next activity without any issue. Can you be more accurate? Whats really happens? Nothing? Did you have some leading logs?

Anyway, I think your original question is answered. If you need more help I suggest you for exemple upload the code to a repository and to share it with me. It will be way easier to review your code and provide help.

Since you seems to start on android, I recommend you to use codelab to improve your skills:
https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/toc-v2?authuser=1

Please have a look at this:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-a-variable-field-property-in-java

Comment: Hello thanks again for everything and yes you are right. I am a starter and I already bought a book for it. With my app I have this problem now. The Activity wont open and show the erreor code Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.die_trinkspielapp.Nameeingabespieler2.onCreate(Nameeingabespieler2.java:47) Do you have any idear why this is?

Comment: Hello, 

Do you follow my leads? Probably because you spinner is null. But I can't tell you why if I don't see the change you did.

As I said in my previous answer share you code on a repository so I'll be able to review it.

Comment: I just looked for some solutions and I finally got it. now everything works. Thanks again for everything.